# remove all log in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging

I wanted to exclude all of the tensorflow logs in output. I searched and found that one or both of these setting should work:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='3'
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```

Though, I am still getting network loading logs, e.g.:

```
2019-02-28 23:51:13,520:INFO::Restoring parameters from ./pre_model/classic/brain4/network--6009999
```

I was wondering if could remove this log too. 
I appreciate any help or comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Place this before importing `tf`.

Comment: I am still getting the INFO: `2019-03-02 08:31:51,731:INFO::Restoring parameters from ./pre_model/classic/brain4/network--6009999`

Comment: If you re running a script, `python -W <name_of_script.py>` which can suppress warnings. Your deleted comment gave me a totally different idea though.

Comment: I am getting `Unknown option: --
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.
`. Beside which deleted comment? I did not send any comment and did not delete any.

Comment: Also, make sure that both of the methods (`logging` and `os`) run before importing tensorflow.